# Cookie not set after adding www to cookie domain

Tags: security, cookies, subdomain, httponly, cookie-httponly

I can't get the cookie set in the browser. This happens when I add www to the cookie domain, but can't figure out why.

#### Problem description

We have a domain `mycompany.com`, an application running under `mycompany.com` and another application under `subdomain.mycompany.com`. Each of them has their own cookie, secure and httpOnly. We don't want this cookies to be shared between domains. We had the domain for the cookie of `mycompany.com` set as `.mycompany.com`. The problem with this is that it leaks to `subdomain.mycompany.com`, so to avoid it I've changed the domain to `www.mycompany.com`. In our apache config, we redirect all requests for `mycompany.com` to `www.mycompany.com` and all traffic is redirected to https.

So when I go to `mycompany.com` or `www.mycompany.com` I end up in `www.mycompany.com`, the domain and the cookie domain match, this should work, but it doesn't. The cookie for `mycompany.com` is not in the local storage (Chrome and Firefox). (I've also tried using just `mycompany.com` as the cookie domain, but as expected the cookie leaks to `subdomain.mycompany.com` as when I used `.mycompany.com`)

Here is the cookie as sent back by the server:

```
my_cookie=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Version=1;Comment=;Domain=www.mycompany.com;Path=/;Max-Age=604800000;Secure;HttpOnly;Expires=Fri, 26 Aug 2016 09:32:40 GMT
```

[Reading about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/6734336), I thought the problem could be the redirection, but this happens regardless of whether I go to `mycompamy.com` or `www.mycompany.com`.

What am I doing wrong?

**PS**: The cookie is not being generated by the application running under mycompany.com, but by another process running under `services.mycompany.com`, which the client sends the requests to in order to get the cookie. Maybe this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> PS: The cookie is not being generated by the application running under
>   mycompany.com, but by another process running under
>   services.mycompany.com, which the client sends the requests to in
>   order to get the cookie. Maybe this could be the problem.

Yes as a security measure, `services.mycompany.com` would only be able to set cookies for `services.mycompany.com` or `.mycompany.com`.

If browsers could set cookies for other domains then this would lead to cookie poisoning attacks (e.g. compromising the Double Submit Cookie CSRF control, allowing Session Fixation or introducing XSS where raw cookie values are reflected in a response).

Even if you do change it so that `www.mycompany.com` sets a `www.mycompany.com` cookie, be aware that `something-outside-your-control.mycompany.com` can set a cookie at `.mycompany.com` level  which your `www.mycompany.com` domain wouldn't know where it had been set from. This is because in the HTTP request only the name and value is sent for the cookie, not the domain from where it was set.